# Rotate XAxis label to 90 degree

Tags: c#, pdf, charts, pdfsharp, migradoc

Hi I am using PDFsharp & MigraDoc to generate column chart. I was wondering, if I can rotate the x axis labels to 90 degree so they come like vertical instead of horizontal. Does any body has any idea? If not, can some one tell me any other library I can use for same purpose?

Comment: [shehan pathirathna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12467484/shehan-pathirathna) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64905657/12695027) saying "https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=193 check this, you can use XAxis instead of YAxis."